# Adivina el número aleatorio

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo el siguiente objetivo: 
Escribe un programa que piense un número de forma aleatoria y le pida al usuario que lo trate de adivinar, el usuario puede intentar adivinar el número cuantas veces quiera hasta encontrar el mismo número.

Como puedo lograr que no se repitan los números en un rango del 1 al 10 ? en pocas palabras que el usuario solo tenga 10 intentos para adivinar el número y si no lo adivina finalice y salga un mensaje `sigue intentando`.

Mi código:

```js
  var numeroAleatorio = parseInt(Math.random()* 10)+1;
  console.log(numeroAleatorio);
  var num;
  while(numeroAleatorio != num){
      num = prompt("Ingrese un número por favor: ");
      if (numeroAleatorio == num){
        console.log("Número igual");
      }else{
        console.log("Sigue intentando");
      }
  }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ser más claro en tu pregunta o poner un ejemplo de lo que deseas obtener? Veo que tu código (a grandes rasgos) funciona sin problemas, pero no encuentro sentido a esta afirmación "tengo predefinido el método en un rango hasta 10 en pasos de 1 en 1." Imagino que te refieres a que obtienes un número del 1 al 10, ¿o es que quieres darle 10 intentos al usuario? Imagino que es algo así lo que quieres por "Como puedo lograr que el método Math.random no repita los números y no se vuelva casi que infinito el adivinar el número?", pero tampoco entiendo bien lo que quieres decir en esa frase.

Comment: Cuando modifiques tu pregunta para satisfacer un comentario deberías dejar otro comentario para que seamos notificados del cambio. Espero que la respuesta que he publicado sea lo que buscas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es llevar un contador de intentos y que tanto los mensajes de que has acertado o que no lo has conseguido estén fuera del bucle que se encarga de repetir la pregunta durante cada intento:

```js
let numeroAleatorio = parseInt(Math.random()* 10)+1;
console.log("Número obtenido", numeroAleatorio);
let num, intentos = 10;
/* Saldremos del bucle si agotamos intentos o acertamos número */
do {
  num = prompt(
    `Ingrese un número (quedan ${intentos} intentos):`
  );
} while(numeroAleatorio != num && --intentos > 0);
/* Detectamos si salimos del bucle por agotar intentos o acertar número */
if (numeroAleatorio == num){
  alert("¡Ha acertado el número!");
} else {
  alert("No lo ha conseguido en 10 intentos, sigue intentando");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    int a=0, n=0;
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean valordevuelto = false;
    int[] numeros_aleatorios = new int[10];
    Random r = new Random();


    //llenar vector con cierta cantidad de numeros aleatorios
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    n = r.nextInt(10)+1;

    valordevuelto=false;
    a=0;
    //if el valor inicial es 0 ponle en valor y rompe
     if(i==0)
        {
        numeros_aleatorios[i]=n;  

        }
     else 
     {
    //comprobacion de numero aleatorios si ya estan en la lista
    while(a<i)
    {
        //if el valor esta dentro del vector no lo agregues y pasa el valor verdadero
        if(n==numeros_aleatorios[a])
        {
        valordevuelto=true;
        break;
        }

       a++; 
    }
    // if no esta en el vector agregalo
      if(valordevuelto==false && i>=0)
      {
        numeros_aleatorios[i-1]=n;  
        System.out.println("\n numero aleatorios que se generaron="+n+"\n");

      }
     //if el valor devuelto es es verdadero por que existe restale uno al vector
      if(valordevuelto==true)
      {
          i=-1;
      }
     }
    }


    //imprimir vector con todos los numero aleatorios no repetidos
    for(int i=0;i<numeros_aleatorios.length;i++)
    {
    System.out.println(""+numeros_aleatorios[i]);
    }
     System.out.println("Ahora juguemos a adivinar los numeros !");
    a=0;
    while(a<numeros_aleatorios.length)
    {
        int numeroparaadivinar = x.nextInt();
        if(numeroparaadivinar==numeros_aleatorios[a])
        {
        System.out.println("Correcto adivinaste el numero , jueguemos de nuevo!");
        a++;    
        }
        else
        {
         System.out.println("oooh! fallaste sigue intentandolo"); 

        }
        if(a==10)
        {
            System.out.println("fin del juego, Ganaste Campeon!");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Es JavaScript, no Java